# How do I handle the event of an element getting added to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an app where clicking a link brings up a modal. In the modal is a form. I need to monitor for that form's submission.

I'm attaching a click handler in my JS like so:

```
$('.vex-dialog-form :submit').click (event) ->
    alert "hi"
```

That alert isn't firing, I believe it's because I need to attach some kind of event handler for that modal loading then put the submit event inside of that.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Before I trigger the modal, `[]`, after I trigger the modal, `[<input type="submit" />]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `event delegation` for dynamically added DOM. use `.on()`:

```
 $('.vex-dialog-form').on('click',':submit',function(){
   alert("hi");
 });
```

if parent `.vex-dialog-form` is also getting added dynamically, then use:

```
 $(document).on('click','.vex-dialog-form :submit',function(){
   alert("hi");
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.vex-dialog-form :submit', function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

In this case `document` is waiting for click and after it gets clicked, jQuery finds out whether your submit button is clicked or not